# Parse files in FileList object

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, grails

I am using FormData to upload multiple files in my grails project.The files needs to be uploaded via Ajax. I have used following code for ajax upload. But in controller, I get the params as [object FileList]. How do I get files from this object. Is there any way to change this object to multipart?

```js
jQuery('#file-save').click(function() {
  if (jQuery('#form input[type="file"]')) {
    var form = jQuery("#form").find('input[type="file"]');

    var picData = new FormData();
    picData.append('userFiles', form.get(0).files);
    picData.append('userId', '$usrId');

    jQuery.ajax({
      url: '/file/upload',
      type: 'post',
      dataType:'json',
      data: picData,
      enctype: "multipart/form-data",
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log("success");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

The controller code is:

```
def upload(){
    def userId = params.userId
    def inputFile = params.userFiles
    println(inputFile)
    inputFile.each{i,j->
        println(i)
        println(j)
    }
}
```

When I debug, I get params.userFiles : "[object FileList]". Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: How to upload a file and read in a file input check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload?rq=1

Comment: The above code works well. For single file upload, I get multipart data which I can easily save to external folder. But for multiple file uploads, I get [object FileList]. I need a way to parse this.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely need to loop through the files client side, adding the same key for each one

```
var picData = new FormData();
// loop through form.get(0).files
picData.append('userFiles', file);
// end loop
picData.append('userId', '$usrId');
```